# How many 4 digit numbers satisfy all of the following conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many $4$ digit numbers satisfy all of the following conditions:

- They have no repeated digits.
- They must contain the digits $3$ and $5$ in some order.
- They are divisible by $2$.

Comment: [202](https://tio.run/##JYtJCoAwDAC/kpsJ9FA3EKGPEWw1oGlJ68HXV8XLwMBMussepZ@S1pqUpWC@TmwhRAUGFtBFNo@ttdZ8sKYj4ACHF8z@rWeXiyITkXMDLLJC0zffmH8ZfyGq9QE), although not clear if $4534$ contains repeated digits or only $5344$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last digit must be one of $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$.

Given this, there are three choices for which place is taken by the $5$.

Given this, there are two choices for which place is taken by the $3$.

Finally, there are $7$ choices for the value of the last digit.

---

This gives $$5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 7 = 210$$ However, we've counted numbers with a leading zero, which shouldn't be considered four-digit numbers. The numbers we've overcounted are of the form $035\text{d}$ and $053\text{d}$, where $d\in \{2,4,6,8\}$. We've therefore overcounted by $8$, so the final answer is $$210 - 8 = \boxed{202}$$

Comment: Pls explain why downvote?

Comment: If I've made an error please let me know and I will fix it :)

Comment: Read 2 times, all is 100% clear and correct and gives that computed $202$. Maybe for answering a question which has no research effort?